# Navigation bar that stays on top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need my navbar to stay on top of the page, but whenever that happens theres a enourmes gap between the top of the page and the nav bar need some help. Thank you in advance HTML kills me. I already tried to run a js file it stays the same way do you guys can think of any way it can work ? I know you can for sure. Once again thanks in advance.

```css
/*Fonte Customuzida dos Simpsons*/
@font-face{
 font-family: 'TheSimpsons';
 src:url('font/SimpsonsFont.otf');
}

/*Estilo da pagina "HOME"*/
body{
 margin: 0;
 background-color: grey;
}

/*Estilo do 'titulo'*/
.titulo{
 top: 0;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: yellow;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url(img/clouds.jpg);
 text-align: center;
 background-size: 40%;
}
.titulo h1{ 
 font-family: TheSimpsons;
 color:yellow;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}

/*Estilo da navBar*/
.navbar{
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: yellow;
 border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}
.navbar ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5%;
  position: center;
  font-family: TheSimpsons;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar li{
 display: inline;
 padding:2px 20px 2px 20px;
}

.navbar a{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 <title>The Simpsons</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="titulo">
  <h1>The Simpsons</h1>
 </div>

 <div class="navbar">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Locais</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Personagens</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Serie</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Filmes</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's Simple,**

Just replace your navbar class in CSS with this.

```
.navbar{
    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}
```

The problem was you have given `position:fixed`, That will fix the navbar exactly where it is, That's whythere was a gap on the top when you scroll.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good luck brother